# Runnable thread inside doInBackground (SwingWorker) ? Help please

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

i am developing a client/server application where i have to use threads to not block the UI, the application looks like:

So, the problem is that i can't specify a priority in SwingWorker, so what i did is:

```
...

        SwingWorker<String, Object> sw = new SwingWorker<String, Object>() {

                        @Override
                        public String doInBackground() {

                       //For example
                       Thread t1 = new Thread(jprogressbar);
                       t1.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
                       t1.start();
                        }
    }


...
```

As you can see it looks pretty weird, because the thread is updating the JProgressBar, so i just want to create multiple tasks (threads) and to update the JProgressBar's, but i want to know the best way to do this, because i'm pretty sure that  i'm not doing the right thing because as you know, swing is not thread-safe, so i used SwingWorker. The application is working pretty fine, but i just want to know if is there a better way to do this?

Thank you, i'd appreciate any answer.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: you can share a link for screenshots.

Comment: create thread pool for any number of threads you want and call start on each thread ....and synchronize that block of run method to have thread safe

Comment: You might want to make sure you need this before you go to the trouble.  I've used progress bars with SwingWorker, and I've never felt any need to mess with priorities at all.  The easiest programming to implement and debug is the stuff you don't have to do.

Comment: @rcook This is not for a real project, i wouldn't use priority, but they want me to do it.

Comment: @KaribasappaGC Yeah that's what i did but the problem is that Swing is not thread-safe.

Comment: Well, "not thread-safe" means that you have to do the synchronization among threads yourself, not that you can't use them.

Comment: yes go ahead and use synchronization..thats what i suggested

Comment: @rcook Do you mean to synchronize the JProgressBar?

Comment: @KaribasappaGC I'll try what you say, but what should I synchronize? JProgressBar, JTable, JFrame,..?

Comment: i am not seeing your run method of thread to suggest properly..but synchronize the block which is updating JProgressBar inside run method..

Comment: @user3478806 SwingWorker is WorkersThread (Runnable#Thread/Thread) that notify EDT, create 3 instances of SwingWorker for 3 separate threads

Comment: @user3478806 please whats `Thread t1 = new Thread(jprogressbar);`, where your rocket fly

Comment: @mKorbe That was a fast example of my problem.. I won't post the whole class haha

Comment: @user3478806 answers/comments are based on your effort, everything in your example is wrong designed, nor you goal is somehow clear

Comment: You are the only one who didn't understand it, maybe it's not my problem, but im not here to discuss if the post is wrong designed, because there are people answering me and i'm answering them. Please tell me what you don't understand and i'll answer you.. don't be rude

Comment: @user3478806: Why not use the worker's existing bound property, `progress`?

Comment: @trashgo I would use it, but i have to specify a priority and swingworker doesn't have the method setPriority();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`SwingWorker`’s class documenation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html):

> Because `SwingWorker` implements `Runnable`, a `SwingWorker` can be submitted to an `Executor` for execution.

So if you want to have control over the background `Thread` that will eventually execute the `doInBackground()` method rather than use the default Swing worker thread it is explicitly permitted to use the fact that `SwingWorker` implements `Runnable` rather than invoking its `execute()` method:

```
SwingWorker<String, Object> sw = new SwingWorker<String, Object>() {
  @Override
  public String doInBackground() {
    // do the real work here
  }
  // override other methods as needed
}
// instead of calling sw.execute() start the background thread yourself:
Thread t1 = new Thread(sw);
t1.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
t1.start();
```

But of course, it would be possible to use an `Executor` as well as the documentation suggested. You can implement your own `Executor` which creates high priority threads or use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and provide a custom `ThreadFactory` which produces high priority threads.

Then, if you have an `Executor e` you can just start the background processing with `e.execute(sw);`.

---

As a side note, you should consider the thread priorities to be a hint rather than an important property. Especially the higher than normal priorities have no effect on most implementations…

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a PropertyChangeListener for this.
You can create a class that extends from Thread, like this:

```
public abstract class UIProcess extends Thread {

    private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void setStatus(int percentage) {
        pcs.firePropertyChange("status", 0, percentage);
    }

    public void addStatusChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

And then you can register your SwingWorker to listem for this events.

```
Thread t = new UIProcess(...);
t.addStatusChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
      int  newStatus = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
      //here you can update your progress bar, with a synchronized method if you think this is necessary
  }
});
```

Comment: There's no need for additional `PropertyChangeSupport`; the worker's `setProgress()` method already notifies listeners.

Comment: Yes, but he is not using the SwingWorker directly, he is using a Thread inside the SwingWorker

Comment: There's no need; listeners are "notified asynchronously on the Event Dispatch Thread."

Comment: @tiagohng Sorry i didn't see your comment inside propertyChange.